# Why can't I use a boolean expression in a SQL CASE expression inside a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, case, boolean-expression

I want to write a query with the following logic:

- If `@fundKey` is greater than 0, look for funds with a key matching `@fundKey`.
- Otherwise, look for funds with a key less than 1000000.

If I were to write this logic in JavaScript it would be something like this:

```
funds.filter(x => fundKey > 0 ? x.FundKey === fundKey : x.FundKey < 1000000)
```

I tried to write a query like this

```
DECLARE @fundKey INT = -1;
SELECT FundKey, FundName FROM dbo.Funds
WHERE CASE WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN FundKey = @fundKey ELSE FundKey < 1000000 END
```

but it seems that the syntax is invalid. Why can't I use the result of a boolean expression in a WHERE clause? Is there a different way to write this logic without being too verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `CASE` expression returns a scalar value *not* a boolean result. Though, you shouldn't be use a `CASE` expression on a column in the `WHERE` anyway; it won't be SARGable. Use explicit `AND` and `OR` logic.

For your query, this means you should actually be doing:

```sql
DECLARE @fundKey INT = -1;

SELECT FundKey,
       FundName
FROM dbo.Funds
WHERE (@fundKey > 0 AND FundKey = @fundKey)
   OR (@fundKey <= 0 AND FundKey < 1000000);
```

Likely, as well, you'll want to add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as the plans could be quite different for the 2 boolean clauses.

Comment: You could make this sargeable with `WHERE FundKey >= CASE WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN @fundKey ELSE 0 END AND FundKey <= CASE WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN @fundKey ELSE 1000000 END` ie the right-side `CASE` expressions only contain variables

Comment: No not quite. This uses an `AND` interval condition, so probably more efficient

Comment: Ahh yeah, I see, I misread instead, @Charlieface . :) It is 5 minutes before the EoD on a Friday though.

Answer (score 3):

In T-SQL, `CASE` is an *expression* that returns a value. It is not for control of flow. Therefore you must say:

```
WHERE FundKey = CASE WHEN @fundKey >  0 THEN @fundKey END
   OR FundKey < CASE WHEN @fundKey <= 0 THEN 1000000  END
```

Since the implicit `ELSE NULL` can't match to `=` or `<`, only one condition can be true for any given row.

Less intuitive, and slightly wordier, but potentially better performance-wise:

```
WHERE FundKey BETWEEN 
         CASE WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN @fundKey ELSE 0      END -- or 1?
     AND CASE WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN @fundKey ELSE 999999 END
```

If you find performance still suffers (which is potentially the case at scale in general or specifically if `FundKey` isn't unique and you have significant skew), you can build the command dynamically, so that you're only performing a scan of all those matching rows when `@fundKey` is `0`.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT FundKey, FundName FROM dbo.Funds'
  + CASE WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN N' WHERE FundKey = @fundKey'
                           ELSE N' WHERE FundKey < 1000000';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql;
```

You can achieve similar with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and no dynamic SQL, but if the direct point lookup is common, or there are potentially other predicates that will be added in, or the query will be run *a lot*, dynamic SQL will provide long-term stability of small number of plans without constant recompiles.

For a lot more on `CASE`, see:

- [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)

For more on dynamic SQL for handling shifting predicates (I call this "the kitchen sink"):

- [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: I understand that CASE is an expression, not a control flow operator. I expect WHERE to accept any expression that returns a boolean. For example, `FundKey = 0` can evaluate to true or false, why can't a CASE expression that evaluates to true or false also be used the same way?

Comment: @PeterOlson But an expression needs to return _a value_ and you need to compare _to that value_. SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, and you can't make a boolean expression pretend to be one. Try to use `FundKey = 0` as output. What does `SELECT x = (FundKey = 0);` do? Some languages have shortcuts that let you evaluate expressions as scalars, T-SQL isn't one of them, at least not in this case (no pun intended).

Comment: The closest data type SQL Server has to a boolean is `bit`, @PeterOlson , which although you can *compare* to the `varchar` value `'true'`/`false'` they aren't a replacement for a boolean; `WHERE BitColumn;` would result in the error *"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"*

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to apply your logic in WHERE clause

```
DECLARE @fundKey INT = -1;
SELECT FundKey, FundName FROM dbo.Funds
WHERE FundKey = (CASE 
                  WHEN @fundKey > 0 THEN @fundKey
                  WHEN @fundKey <= 0 AND FundKey < 1000000 THEN FundKey
                  ELSE 0 
                END)
```

Since CASE expressions are not sargable in WHERE clause, so the performance of this query could be not good as using explicit AND and OR logic. It's just a demonstration of how we could use CASE expression.